# How to correctly pass on/update data from socket to other classes?

Tags: java, string, sockets, server, client

I have a problem with sending data from my ServerData-class to other classes.
The problem is that while in the while-loop the data is correctly updated. If I do `System.out.println(inData);` or `System.out.println(str);` as well as `System.out.println.(this.toString());` in the while loop the data will come out like this:

```
ID=1144831794931864;X=218;Y=100;TYPE=3
ID=1144831794934430;X=268;Y=131;TYPE=3
ID=1144831794935712;X=107;Y=15;TYPE=2
ID=1144831794936140;X=27;Y=182;TYPE=3
```

Different ID, cordinates and types.

However, if I try to use the updated String like this:

```
while(true){
        System.out.println(str); //shows same data/not updated.
    }
```

or `this.toString();` in another class, the same data is being shown:

```
ID=1145076069027748;X=244;Y=73;TYPE=3
ID=1145076069027748;X=244;Y=73;TYPE=3
ID=1145076069027748;X=244;Y=73;TYPE=3
ID=1145076069027748;X=244;Y=73;TYPE=3
ID=1145076069027748;X=244;Y=73;TYPE=3
```

As you can see all the information is same.
Does anyone know how I can solve this?

The ServerData-class:

```
public class ServerData implements Runnable{

    private long id;
    private int xPos;
    private int yPos;
    private int type;

    private String str;

    private Thread thread;
    private boolean running;

    private Socket socket;

    public ServerData(Socket socket){
        this.socket = socket;
        this.start();

        while(true){
            System.out.println(str); //shows same data/not updated.
        }   
    }

    public synchronized void start() {
        running = true;
        thread = new Thread(this, "Server");
        thread.start();
    }

    public synchronized void stop() {
        running = false;
        try {
            thread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }

    public void run(){
        BufferedReader in = null;
        try {
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String inData = null;
        try {
            while((inData = in.readLine()) != null){
//              System.out.println(inData);
                str = inData;
                this.setString(str);

                String filteredData = inData.replaceAll("[^0-9;]", ""); //
                String[] tmp = filteredData.split(";");

                id = Long.parseLong(tmp[0]);
                xPos = Integer.parseInt(tmp[1]);
                yPos = Integer.parseInt(tmp[2]);
                type = Integer.parseInt(tmp[3]);


//              System.out.println(this.toString()); //shows correct data.

//              System.out.println("ID: "+ id + " xPos: " + xPos + " yPos: " + yPos +" Type: " + type);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void setID(long id){
        this.id = id;
    }

    public long getID(){
        return id;
    }

    public int getXPos(){
        return xPos;
    }

    public int getYPos(){
        return yPos;
    }

    public int getType(){
        return type;
    }

    public void setString(String str){
        System.out.println(str); //shows correct data.
        this.str = str;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return str;
    }

}
```